# Atom x86 Tablet, Can't access camera when screen is off and ConnectedStandby off

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-management

(Also posted the question here : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c988f9c-39c2-42ec-968b-572d23deaea0/atom-tablet-cant-access-camera-when-screen-is-off-and-connectedstandby-off?forum=win10itprohardware)

I have this atom tablet (http://www.utok.ro/800-series/utok-i800) that I upgraded to windows 10. And decided to use it as an unattended proxy server. With works fine with connected standby disabled . I even keep it on battery quite often and it easily gives me more than 10 hours serving as a proxy because it doesn't keep the screen on.

I wanted to add webcam viewing in browser capabilities and used this modified python script https://gist.github.com/n3wtron/4624820

(the modified version is here https://github.com/ovidiubuligan/PythonHttpWebCam but the problem also happens with the basic version)

I access the tablet via teamviewer to do deployments and configurations.

Python mjpeg script works perfectly when the screen is on (teamviewer session is running  or i tap the screen to keep it awake).

**The problem is**: as soon as the display shuts down the running python script can't capture any new images from the device. Tapping the screen or connecting via teamviewer imediatley resumes capturing images. In the meantime the proxy server handles requests without issues.

Is there a way to wake up the camera from code without the screen ?